# Convert Double to String: Culture specific

Tags: c#

Let's say my method has a argument of type Double. but sometimes what I pass is an int like 7 and not a double like 7.0 , so if I use ToString method then 7 will be "7" , but I want it to be "7.0",  now I also need to consider the culture because some times maybe French is using "," for decimal so it should be "7,0" ... how can I do this conversion to string?

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for this?

```
double x = 7.0;

String Display = x.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
```

Comment: it is close! 
Input: 7
output: "7,0"   or maybe "7.0"  dependant on the current culture.

Comment: Use hashes instead of zeros, that should allow it to add the separator if needed. So : `x.ToString("#.##", ...)` and that should hopefully spit out 7. Test it with 6.9 to make sure it outputs 6,9 as expected.

Comment: Josua: changing 0.0 to #.# did worked like a champ. thank you both.

Comment: ok, still a problem: if input is 7 it does NOT return 7.0 it just returns 7

Answer (score 5):

Besides all the correct answers to your question I'd like to hint you into using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for any scenario where you are about to store data into a file, database etc.

Had I known this earlier, it would have saved me lots of time and pain.

Answer (score 2):

It already is culture sensitive, it pays attention to the Thread.CurrentCulture property.  That won't be English when a French user is running your program.  Don't do anything special unless you know for a fact that the default culture is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

> string.format

msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx