# Convert double in c#

Tags: c#

I need to convert a double using the ',' separator to a double using the '.' separator ie, xxx,xx to xxx.xx, under all locales. Anyone got a c# function to do that?

Comment: Obligatory response: Yes, I do.

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert a string representing a number with a , as decimal separator, to a string representing the same number with a "."? Did you consider the Replace method?

Comment: This might be relevant for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877664/convert-double-to-string-culture-specific

Comment: Ok, I need to be more specific: I convert string dates to integer Julian dates and then write them to an SQLite database. The database uses Reals for the date fields. Further, the Julian date needs to be in the form xxxxxxx.5. Adding 0.5 to the integer generates the required double value. However, if the user's locale uses the ',' decimal separator, SQLite crashes when the date field is written; SQLite doesn't accept double values values created by ',' decimal separator locales. Hope this is clearer. Not sure how to handle this!

Comment: Thinking more clearly about this, the real issue is that my SQLite DB isn't handling the locale correctly wrt to real/double values. Will investigate further.

Comment: Using: CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB") as the 1st parameter in the sqlite statement's string.Format function fixes the problem. Thanks for clearing my head on this.

Answer (score 6):

The decimal point might not be represented by the period character in your current culture.

In general, when performing culture-invariant conversions, it's best to specify CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as the IFormatProvider argument to the method:

```
Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(decimal), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Convert.ChangeType(a, typeof(double), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

take what you want

Comment: I like this because it uses decimal instead of double.  IMHO, there are rare cases where double is the actual desired data type.