# Double ToString("C") culture specific

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

I know that this works ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877664/convert-double-to-string-culture-specific)):

```
double x = 9.7;
x.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL"));
```

But I have this code in my code behind:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

and in my aspx webform, I'd like to use `double.tostring("C")` so no cultureinfo there. Because it is set on the current thread. But the local machine is `nl-NL`. The CurrentThread is set to en-GB in the code behind, but the valutasign is still a euro sign instead of pound.

Am I missing something? Or is using the overload of tostring with the cultureinfo required? In other words, do I have to rewrite all double tostrings to use cultureinfo?

Comment: Where in codebehind do you assign the `CurrentCulture`? However, it's  not that clear what you want. You say that the first snippet works, then 1.) Why don't you use it? 2.) You want pound instead of euro sign, so why do  you use `x.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL"))`?

Comment: Then just use `x.ToString("C")` if you _sure_ you assing your current thread culture as `en-GB`?

Comment: @xanatos: i thought the whole lifeycle is processed from the same thread, do you have a link?

Comment: Tim, because I have a lot of double tostrings in my aspx files. I like one central place to set the culture to the thread, which i did but does not affect the aspx files rendering. @SonerGönül I am sure, debugger says so. But it does not work. And Xanatos, I like to switch depending on logged on user. and not for all users, just english to show pounds, otherwise euro's

Comment: @JPHellemons: you haven't answered the question where you change the current-culture. You have to do that in `Page_PreInit` not `Init` or `Load`. Also, where do you use `double.tostring("C")`? Can you show that code, is it on the aspx or in codebehind?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it is already in the question : `in my aspx webform, I'd like to use double.tostring("C") so no cultureinfo there` and about the events. I have a full redirect to the same page to force a full reload. even navigating to other aspx files do not affect the valuta sign even though the currentthread has en-gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you initialize the culture soon enough in the page life cycle.  In fact, there's even a method for you to override specially for this purpose: [`Page.InitializeCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture).

Example based on a cookie:

```
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        var cookie = Request.Cookies[WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocaleCookieName"]];
        if (cookie != null)
            Culture = UICulture = cookie.Value;
    }
```

No need to call the base method, see the documentation for more information.

Comment: Too bad that this is not possible on my masterpage. Will test it for a single aspx

Comment: @JPHellemons You might want to reconsider your design. Most applications will use one or more `Page` subclasses that arbitrary pages will derive from. If it turns out that all pages that use a certain master page need the same `Page` supertype, then you can create one for these pages only. Often, you'll find that master page relationships are not inherently tied to `Page` type hierarchies, in which cases the extra flexibility comes in handy.