# Does Math.Round in .NET round certain values incorrectly?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

For example,

```
double a = 2.55;
double b = Math.Round(a, 1); // expected result is 2.5
Console.WriteLine(b); // 2.6
```

The reason we expect `2.5` there is that the closest 64-bit IEEE 754 float to `2.55` is exactly `2.54999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875`, so whether we're using `MidpointRounding.ToEven` or `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` the value should round down to `2.5`.

On the other hand, the "F" format specifier seems to handle the rounding correctly.

```
double a = 2.55;
Console.WriteLine($"{a:F1}"); // 2.5
```

**Edit:** It looks like the .NET team is tracking basically the same issue with `Math.Round` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1643). According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47244), the issue might be addressed in the upcoming .NET 7 but it's not certain.

Comment: The default rounding mode for Round() is MidpointRounding.ToEven.  That's what you got, you'll like Math.Round(a, 1, MidpointRounding.ToZero) better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your actual question "Does Math.Round in .NET round certain values incorrectly?" is: ***Yes***. (Well, Microsoft would probably argue that this behaviour is defined, and is therefore correct.)

The reason for this is described in [the documentation for `Math.Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-int32-system-midpointrounding)):

> Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing
> decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic
> operations on floating-point values, in some cases the Round(Double,
> Int32, MidpointRounding) method may not appear to round midpoint
> values as specified by the mode parameter. This is illustrated in the
> following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13 instead of 2.14.
> This occurs because internally the method multiplies value by
> 10^digits, and the multiplication operation in this case suffers from a
> loss of precision.

We can test this:

```
double a = 2.55;
double c = a * Math.Pow(10, 1); // "a * 10.0" gives the same result.

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("f16"));
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("f16"));
```

The output is:

```
 2.5499999999999998
25.5000000000000000
```

You can see that the value after multiplication by 10^1 is 25.5, which will be rounded up in the next step of the rounding algorithm.

You can look at [the actual implementation here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Math.cs,def1acf99267ac6f).

It's a bit fiddly, but the answer is really "something something rounding something" ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the Microsoft docs. I was looking for something like this but didn't find it. The question then is why does the "F" format specifier work "correctly". Doesn't it internally do a similar thing?

Comment: @bjorn93: the formatting algorithms are far more intricate, as they need to cover many more cases (and they've been wrong in the past). The gory details are [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Dragon4.cs) (with comments linking to the original papers).

Comment: @bjorn93 What Jeroen said, and also note that the `Math.Round()` algorithms are intended to be fast whereas the string formatting algorithms can afford to be (and are) much slower. As it [mentions here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150330014345/http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/): `Dragon4 and its derivatives are complicated and tricky, and they have a hefty performance cost, since they rely on arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic to compute their results.`

Comment: Agreed that the binary rounding is better than converting to string. However, if you are looking for a faster number to string algorithm than Dragon4, see https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is the Dragon4 what's internally used for the decimal-to-string conversion in c# (which would differ from what's used in the Math.Round method)?

Comment: @bjorn93 Yes the Dragon4 implementation is used for C# numeric string formatting.

Comment: @bjorn93: if you want the starting point, that's [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs#L520), which is in turn called from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Double.cs#L339). (Walking up or for that matter down the stack is not so convenient from Github, which is why I linked directly to the implementation.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson just FYI, the .NET team seem to be tracking basically the same issue (I think) [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1643). I added this to my post.

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation for rounding in .NET is "Round half to even" which is "Bankers Rounding". This means that mid-point values are rounded towards the nearest even number.

Comment: Please read my question again. This doesn't address what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Round(value,decimal)` works as expected. You define your value as `2.55` and thought you are rounding `2.55` aka `2.54999999...` in IEEE 754 but this is false. Rounding with decimal apply a power of 10 to the rounding. So your `2.55` with 1 decimal is apply a single power of 10 so it become `25.5` which is perfectly represented as `25.5` in IEEE 754. Then a rounding become `26.0` then it divide by the factor back to `2.6` hence your results.

Answer (score 0):

Because 2.55 is a midway value, it uses the convention when rounding. Default this is "To Even". So in this case it rounds to the closest even, 2.6.
If you use AwayFromZero it will do the same in this case, if you rounded 2.65 it would give different results.

Strange, I get the same result with the string formatter... ? Maybe it's a cultural setting. See also [Convert Double to String: Culture specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877664/convert-double-to-string-culture-specific)